# Iframe allow tag not supported in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I tried adding the allow="microphone" tag in iframe that I added in salesforce lightning component, but when I load the page it throws a `Uncaught AuraFriendlyError`. Is it not supported, also if not is there any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is blocked by lockerservice .You can find more details using [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

[image]

You can disable the locker by using an API version equal to 39.0 or below in your aura component . However note that this is a security violation and locker service is recommended to keep your component secure .